# Cross referencing objects management

Tags: reference, lua

Often I would have an unit and node object. Units are required to know which node they are at and nodes have to know the units its holding. This means that they each have a reference to each other. The problem I have is that I can see this getting messy since moving a unit to a new node means also having to update the reference for the nodes too. Is there a easier way to model/organize this relationship? This specific example is in lua but the question applies to any language.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to manage one side using a caching protocol.  If the information changes, invalidate the cache.  Then, when the side needs the information again, it obtains it.

In your example, perhaps the node has an authoritative list of units, while each unit only caches which node it is on.  Perhaps these units are stopped and started, and the unit can simply look up which node it is attached to when it starts?